# a software similar to ExaGear( linux Raspberry pi 4 raspbian)

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, emulator, terminal-emulator

everyone thanks for taking the time and looking at my question. first off I wanna explain what a problem I'm having then what I'm searching for.

**The Problem/Usage**

I'm trying to run a FiveM or Teamspeak (basically any kind of 64x bit) server on my Raspberry pi 4 (4gb Ram Linux (raspbian)) if I start the server on the 32x bit raspbian I'm getting an error that it can't execute the code because of the 64x bit requirement so now what I need is a software like exaGear(a software that somehow emulating a 64x terminal) I don't have any plan on what alternative software is in existing I tried to download ExaGear but its out of Order alsow the download website is down. if anybody has an idea how to instal ExaGear working or an alternativ programm please help me.

---

**Searching for**
simply ExaGear or any software that does the same thing

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. Missing is e.g. what features you need, and how much you'd be willing to spend if it came to paid software. Could you please [edit] your post and add those? Thanks!